# How to write an InputStream bytes to string?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have a InputStream, which contains a large file (about 20 mb) and I want to slowly (part by part) write in to JsonWriter. I've tried to use buffer, but it called only one time. How to implement this?

```
   val buf = ByteArray(8192)
    inputStream.use { fin ->
        while (fin.read(buf) >= 0) {
            actualWriter.write(Base64.encodeToString(buf, Base64.DEFAULT))
        }
    }
```

Note, my app uses `minSdkVersion 21`

Comment: Your code will not work, because base64 encode can't be used do encode block-wise. Use base64 in stream mode using [Base64.Encoder.wrap(...)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.Encoder.html#wrap-java.io.OutputStream-) instead.

Comment: And 20 MB isn't a large file in 2019.

Comment: For pdf or jpg it's pretty big value

Comment: @GhostCat And Android app should not waste memory and ecoding 20MB means that you need 20MB (input data) + (20 * 4 / 3 * 2 = ~53) MB (4/3 for base64 and *2 for UTF-16 string representation).

Comment: @Hitrene if you can't use the Java Base64 encoder stream I only know `Base64OutputStream` from `org.apache.commons.codec` package (third party lib).